# How to filter available applications in web activities FirefoxOS to avoid application calling itself

Tags: javascript, firefox-os

In my application I want to define both - share and pick activities. But then, when I call "pick" activity within my application - it allows my to choose my own application, which makes loop hole. Can I avoid this somehow?

```
 "activities": {
    "share": {
  "href": "./share-activity.html",
  "disposition": "window",
  "filters": {
    "type": ["image/*","image/jpeg","image/png"]
  },
  "returnValue": true
},
"pick": {
  "href": "./pick-activity.html",
  "disposition": "inline",
  "filters": {
    "type": ["image/*","image/jpeg","image/png"]
  },
  "returnValue": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
"activities": {
"pick": {
  "href": "./index.html",
  "disposition": "inline",
  "filters": {
        "type": "image/*",
        "appname": "abc"
  },
  "returnValue": true
}
}
```

Then in your code that calls the pick activity you can avoid your app by calling:

```
var pick = new MozActivity({
   name: "pick",
   data: {
     type: "image/*",
     appname: "xyz"
        }
});
```

Adding appname: "abc" or deleting the appname field will show your app in the list.
Example Code: [github.com/JasonWeathersby/TestActivity](http://github.com/JasonWeathersby/TestActivity)

Comment: it should show for all calls that do not specify an app name or a call that specifiies abc.  In your case to hide the app from itself just enter xyz in the pick so it will not show your own app in the list

Comment: In manifest i have added: "appname" : "PicUp" and in pick call:  appname: "camera" and it still shows my application...

Comment: can you post a link to the code?  and what Firefox OS version are you using?

Comment: Take a look at this sample: https://github.com/JasonWeathersby/TestActivity I noticed in your code you added the appname field to your share activity not your pick.